# mocha test exceeded timeout

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

For some reason I am getting a mocha timeout although the response returns with 202 success... I have several other tests that are written in the exact same fashion and there is no timeout:

```
describe('PUT /api/editTenant', function() {
        it('it should change an existing tenant', function(done) {
            should.exist(test_tenant.tenant_id);
            var body = { 
                email : "test@example.com", 
                message: "Hello!", 
                tenant_id : test_tenant._id, 
                searchOpts : {} 
            };
            request(host).put('/api/edit').send(body).end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.should.have.status(202);
                done();
            });
        });
});
```

And here is the code being tested:

```
exports.editTenant = function(req, res) {
    Tenant.findOneAndUpdate({ _id : tenant.tenant_id }, {
        email           : req.body.email,
        phone           : req.body.phone,
        searchOpts      : req.body.searchOpts,
        contactMessage  : req.body.message
    }, function(err, affected) {
        if(err) res.json(401, err);
        res.json(202, { updated : affected } );
    });
};
```

Again I have several tests just like this and there is no timeout... Is the problem that I'm doing a put not a post?

Comment: Can you humor us and update `if(err) res.json(401, err);` to `if (err) return res.json(401,err)`?

Comment: well i got a 401 error... but not sure why this would be the case. The request works in postman.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the timeout of the mocha

1. this.timeout(20000); // 20seconds you can have any value

   example:you can change your code like

describe('PUT /api/editTenant', function() {

```
it('it should change an existing tenant', function(done) {

   this.timeout(20000); // add this code        

    should.exist(test_tenant.tenant_id);
```

2. mocha yourCode.js -t 10s // while running the code add -t parameter